# Scheme Recursion/Cons

Tags: recursion, scheme, cons

I am at the beginning of the road. I tried to understand this `cons` part  for 2-3 hours, but I have fallen into trouble. I couldn't understand this cons part. How does it combine `'a d'` according to result?

```
(define remv
  (lambda (x ls)
    (cond
      [(null? ls) '()]
      [(eqv? (car ls) x) (remv x (cdr ls))]
      [else (cons (car ls) (remv x (cdr ls)))])))
```

When I put a input like this:

```
> (remv 'b '(a b b d))
```

I get `(a d)`.

But I couldn't understand how it became `'a d'`.

Comment: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Racket_Syntax.html This is some obligatory reading for you. It explains a bit more about lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all occurrences of `x` from a list `ls`, you have three cases to consider:

1. `ls` is empty, in which case the result is also empty,
2. The first element of `ls` is equal to `x`, in which case you just drop it and return the rest of the list after you have removed all `x`es from it,
3. The first element of `ls` is different from `x`, in which case you keep that element and stick it at the front of a list which has no `x`es in it.

Comment: Thanks for paid attantion